# How I Can Use Different Fonts In Tow Language?

Tags: css

In Arabic World We Use Some English Words In Article , But The Problem is, When I Use Arabic Font the English Word's be ugly ، and when use English Font Arabic Word's Be ugly . What is the solution? - Sorry For The Language It's Too Weak.

Comment: So do you just want to use multiple fonts on one webpage?

Comment: tag the english words for example and use a different font on those.

Comment: "Rpm192" Yes With English Language Font A and With Arabic Language Use Font B

Comment: @AbdullahWaleed See my answer below and tell me whether that works for you or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## @import css font-family

You can use the [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) rule to import an Arabic font.

`@import` allows you to import a style sheet into another style sheet. The @import must be at the top of the document (CSS), and @import statements must be declared outside any selectors.

This is my solution to your problem:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/amiri.css);
p {
  display: inline;
}

.arabic {
  font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
}


}
.english {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="arabic"> مرحبا بالعالم</p>
  <p class="english">Hello world</p>
</div>
```

More arabic fonts can be found [at Google Fonts homepage](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=arabic)